# PDO select only returns first row

Tags: php, sql

I want to select several rows from my database and get each id where the name, material and size fits the binded value. I have tried doing this, but I only get the first row back:

```
foreach($_POST["txtName"] as $key => $name){
   if(!empty($name) || !empty($_POST["txtMaterial"][$key]) || !empty($_POST["txtSize"][$key])){
       echo $name.' '.$_POST["txtMaterial"][$key].' '.$_POST["txtSize"][$key];
            
       $sQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = :sName AND material = :sMaterial AND size = :sSize');
       $sQuery->bindValue(':sName', $name);
       $sQuery->bindValue(':sMaterial', $_POST["txtMaterial"][$key]);
       $sQuery->bindValue(':sSize', $_POST["txtSize"][$key]);
       $sQuery->execute();
       $aOrders = $sQuery->fetchAll();
            
       foreach($aOrders as $aOrder){
           echo 'x';
       }
   }

}
```

From the `echo` before the query I get this back:

```
" 3 20BACURI 2 4ELVA  "
```

Which is the material, size, name and material, size, name of two products. However, I only get the row of the first one back. Can anyone help me out why that is?

```
    <input name='txtName[]' class='txtName' type='text'><div class='nameOfProduct'>".$aCategoryName['name']."</div>
         <div class='add'>
             <div id='adding'>+</div>
         </div>
```

The value of the name is added in js when clicked on the .add class:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    $placeholder = $(this).siblings('.nameOfProduct').html()
    $(this).siblings('.txtName').val($placeholder)
})
```

Comment: Where does `$_POST["txtName"]` come from, and is it an array? Show that HTML.

Comment: @Qirel I have added it to the question now

Comment: Why is this being downvoted instead of people helping?

Comment: @caroline4321 - It's probably getting downvoted because it's impossible to solve your issue without knowing more details.  You have to show the actual data from the database (in your question as a table -no image).  I can't see why it shouldn't return one row based on what you have supplied. Please clarify what the data is and why it should return more than one row.